# Azure Data Factory Mapping Data Flow - Azure Managed Instance is NO longer valid as Connector?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I noticed all my datasets from Azure Managed Instance are NO longer available on any Mapping Data Flow activity. And I am pretty sure they were working on few weeks back (before Sep 2020). After some research on Internet, I can only see a new document was released by Microsoft on 31/08/2020 and it is indicating the MI is NOT valid as Connector for Azure Data Factory, Mapping Data Flow. The document is in here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview .

Is anyone having the same issue on this? Or was there an announcement from Microsoft on this change?  Any information would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

SQL MI in data flows will soon be available as a public preview. You can use it in private preview until then. We'll just need your Azure Subscription ID to enable it for you.

Can you click on the ADF feedback link at the top of the ADF UI and submit a feedback request stating your request to enable SQL MI as private preview with your Azure sub ID?

Please include my name on there: Mark Kromer

[image]